# How can i push the employee data in Australia payroll api (PayrollAUApi)? - Xero

Tags: c#, .net, xero-api

When I try to access the PayrollAUApi, I'm getting an error. FYI please find the attachment below.

```
string accessToken = xeroToken.AccessToken;

string xeroTenantId = xeroToken.Tenants[0].TenantId.ToString();

var PayrollAUApi = new PayrollAUApi();
 
var response = await PayrollAUApi.GetEmployeesAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId);
```

[image]

Comment: Can't read that image, can you post it as text? Though the readable part says "Payroll has not been purchased", so are you sure your organisation has a Payroll system to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Global edition of Xero thus does not have payroll functionality. To use Australia Payroll API, we need to have an Australian edition of Xero. So I've created the App with the Australian region in the Xero platform. Now I can able to access the PayrollAUApi & I can able to push the employee data to the Xero payroll platform.